# access model field in serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

key and data are dictionary how I can access data of specific key [image: django admin] in serializer

```
 class Setting(models.Model):
      key = models.CharField(max_length=255, primary_key=True)
      data = JSONField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Comment: Show your serializer code. Actually you posted model for now

Comment: is the huge code I want to access  key and data in the serializer class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In serializer, something like this

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from snippets.models import Snippet, LANGUAGE_CHOICES, STYLE_CHOICES


class SettingsSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    sample_filed = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = Settings
        fields = ('key', 'data', 'sample_filed')

     def get_sample_field(self):
        """ a sample field function to demonstrate srialzer method"""
        """ you can access all keys here as self.key "
         return self.key + self.data
```

Note:- By using model serializer you will just have to specify the model. then restframework will handle all generic stuff. 
you can use serializer methodfield() if you want extra field in the response. there you can use the key as stated above

(or) you can use django -orm

you can use django orm queries outside the serializer.

to get a specific row 
`Settings.objects.get(key = 'key-value')` (only if key is unique. this will throw an exception if there is no value)

(or)

`Settings.objects.filter(key = 'key-value')` (recommded. will give you all the results.)

`Settings.objects.all()` will give you all records

`Settings.objects.filter(key = 'sdaf', data = 'sds')` Specific records with key and data .

Comment: No  if i  print(Setting.objects.filter(key='ssh-port'))  return <QuerySet [<Setting: ssh-port>]>

Comment: yes, you have the result there <QuerySet [<Setting: ssh-port>]>  = result. Its in list format. so say x = Setting.objects.filter(key='ssh-port'). Then x[0] will give you the first record. if there are many records, then you have to iterate them .

Comment: and print(Setting.object.all()) return all key

Comment: Yes. again it will be a list. you need iterate

Comment: if you find this answer solving the issue. Can you kindly accept it @mehranmotmaen

Comment: x[0] return ssh-port  but x[1]  list index out of range

Comment: because there is only one result. so x[0] is returning 1st record. check length of x then you will find it as 1. so its just x[0] in this case

Comment: in Django admin, I have  key and value  and I want value from specific key(each key has value)

Comment: You mean Django admin , either settings.py where we would have add all environment variables ?

Comment: If so you can import settings from ‘ from django.conf import settings’ then use settings[“key”] to get the value

Comment: m=Setting.objects.all()
        print(m.values('key'))
        print(m.values('data'))                      first print show all key second print show all data  but i want data related to spefic key

Comment: can u give me an example what you are expecting from the above table. like if you want data related to ssh-port then this will work. for x in Settings.objects.filter(key='ssh-port') : print (x.data) #gives all data column. print(x.data['value']) # will give u value as per above table, since u have stored it in json format.

Answer (score 0):

work with this code

```
        ssh_instance = Setting.objects.get(key='ssh-port')
        print(ssh_instance.data["value"])
```